# removing scientific notation from axis tick labels in matplotlib (log scale)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have the following figure and as you can see there is an overlapping on y-axis tick labels at 3000, 4000 and 5000 due to the scientific notation of 3x10^3, 4x10^3 and 5x10^3 although I am forcing my own tick labels, My question is how can I remove those ?

I tried `plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain')` but this gives an error: **"AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter."**

```
# multivariate plot of price by cut and color, for approx. 1 carat diamonds
myticks = [2300, 2600, 3000, 3300, 3600, 4000, 4300, 4600, 5000]
ytick_names = ['{}'.format(tick) for tick in myticks]

diamonds_sub = diamonds[diamonds['carat'].between(0.5, 1.5)]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
sb.pointplot(data=diamonds_sub, x='color', y='price', hue='cut')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.yticks(myticks, ytick_names);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding `plt.gca().set_yticklabels([], minor=True)`